# Disable component even without knowing type

Tags: unity-game-engine, components

How do i disable components without knowing about its type?
The best i got is this, but there is no `enabled` option on component?

```
Component[] tmpComponents = tmpGO.GetComponents <Component>();
foreach (Component tmpComponent in tmpComponents)
{
    if ( tmpComponent.GetType() != Transform && tmpComponent.GetType() != MeshRenderer )
    {
        tmpComponent.enabled = false; <= ???
    }
}
```

i also tried

```
tmpGO.GetComponent <tmpComponent.GetType()> ().enabled = false;
```

But that did not work.

Updated:
I try this, but now it is giving different length.

```
Component[] components = tmpGO.GetComponents <Component> ();
Behaviour[] behaviours = tmpGO.GetComponents <Behaviour>();
for (int x = 0; x < components.Length; x++)
{
    if ( components[x].GetType() != typeof (Transform) && components[x].GetType() != typeof (MeshRenderer) )
    {
        Debug.Log (components.Length);
        Debug.Log (behaviours.Length);
        //behaviours [x].enabled = false;
    }
}
```

This does not work because asking for behaviour does not give me a full list of components that could be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is trying to warn you that class `Component` does not have a property/field named `enabled` -- and it doesn't, because there are some component types that cannot be enabled/disabled.

You can, however, filter out to components with type `Behaviour`:

```
foreach (var b in tmpGO.GetComponents<Behaviour>()) {
    b.enabled = false;
}
```

Quoting from the manual:

> Behaviours are Components that can be enabled or disabled.

Comment: Ok, but how do i compare its type? if i have to disable everything, then i might as well just disable the gameobject?

Comment: @user3014330 If you want only a specific type or types of components, I would normally do that filtering with the `GetComponents` type argument. Whatever type you specify, it will only return components of that type.

Comment: Well, my goal was mainly to re-enabled script after they are place on screen, like through a build system.
So i end up using <Monobehaviour>, but i wish components would just complain that certain could not be disabled instead of none-at-all...

Comment: @user3014330 I sympathize with your complaint, but that's not how the type system works. If you want a list of all the Components that can be disabled, what you're actually asking for is a list of Behaviours.

Comment: I know that this can be done by the unity team. I end up needing to disabled any collision box too. Sigh....